# Using JS WebSocket inside a Docker compose network

Tags: python, docker, nginx, websocket, fastapi

I am currently developing a bidirectional API using Python FastAPI as the backend and ReactJS as the frontend. As the API calls should be scalable, I want to create multiple replicas that can be accessible via an Nginx server that also runs in Docker. Here is my docker compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:

  api:
    build:
      context: api
    ports:
      - 8000

  load_balance:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./dimer_api/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:rw
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  gui:
    build:
      context: gui
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - load_balance
```

The FastAPI code looks like:

```py
websockets = []

@router.websocket("/api/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    try:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.receive_text()

            data = {"status": "ok", "type": "message", "message": message}

            await websocket.send_text(json.dumps(data))

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        websockets.remove(message)


def create_app(debug: bool = False) -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI(debug=debug)

    app.include_router(router)

    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=["*"],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

    return app
```

And here one could see the UseEffect from my ReactJS script which is trying to establish a WebSocket connection.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/api/ws"); // ERROR

  socket.onopen = () => {
    console.log("WebSocket connection opened");
  };

  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    const newData = JSON.parse(event.data);
    setData(newData);
  };

  return () => {
    socket.close();
  };
}, []);
```

To provide all information, here is the configuration file of the API:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8000;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://api:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

And the .conf file of the ReactJS app which also runs on a Nginx server:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://load_balance:8000;
  }

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

However, I am facing issues with establishing WebSocket connections between the frontend and backend. The important part is the following, where I don't know what to properly connect to:

```js
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/api/ws");
```

How can I use the `/api` proxy from the GUI to connect to the WebSocket of the FastAPI? Or how could I establish this connection?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **"load_balance"** instead of **"<strike>localhost</strike>"**:

```
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://load_balance:8000/api/ws");
```

also, you can use postman for WebSocket testing.

Comment: When I implement these changes and connect via localhost to the react app, the connection cannot be established to load_balance.